# change image using foo color box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

will it be possible to display an image inside a container div every time i click on a foo color box? if so can someone please show me how. i need to know what the javascript is going to be i have no idea how to make this work using javascript

```css
 .foo {
      float: left;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }
    .white {
      background: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .yellow {
      background: #FAFF38;
    }
    .orange {
      background: #FFA200;
    }

    .red {
      background: #FF0000;
    }
    .dorange {
      background: #FF5500;
    }
    .lgreen {
      background: #80FF00;
    }

    .green {
      background: #45C731;
    }

    .turk {
      background: #17DDBC;
    }
    .lblue {
      background: #00A2FF;
    }.blue {
      background: #1713F6;
    }.purple {
      background: #AB09D3;
    }.black {
      background: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<div id="colour">
                <div class="foo white" data-image="http://mebe.co/mustang">
                </div>
                <div class="foo black" data-image="http://mebe.co/ford">
                </div>
                <div class="foo yellow" data-image="http://mebe.co/f150">
                </div>
                <div class="foo orange" data-image="http://mebe.co/yukon">
                </div>
                <div class="foo red" data-image="http://mebe.co/370z">
                </div>
                <div class="foo dorange" data-image="http://mebe.co/gtr">
                </div>
                <div class="foo lgreen" data-image="http://mebe.co/sentra">
                </div>
                <div class="foo green" data-image="http://mebe.co/dodge">
                </div>
                <div class="foo turk" data-image="http://mebe.co/civic">
                </div>
                <div class="foo lblue" data-image="http://mebe.co/gmc">
                </div>
                <div class="foo blue" data-image="http://mebe.co/bmw">
                </div>
                <div class="foo purple" data-image="http://mebe.co/sentra">
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:lightgrey; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; width:500px; height:500px;  z-index:1; visibility:; float: left; visibility:; background-color: lightgrey;visibility:;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can like this, just update the `data-image`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foo.active').each(function(){
   $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
  });
  $('.foo').on('click',function(){
   $('.container img').attr('src', '');
   $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.yellow {
  background: #FAFF38;
}
.orange {
  background: #FFA200;
}
.red {
  background: #FF0000;
}
.dorange {
  background: #FF5500;
}
.lgreen {
  background: #80FF00;
}
.green {
  background: #45C731;
}
.turk {
  background: #17DDBC;
}
.lblue {
  background: #00A2FF;
}
.blue {
  background: #1713F6;
}
.purple {
  background: #AB09D3;
}
.black {
  background: #000000;
}
.container {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}
.container img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colour">
  <div class="foo white active" data-image="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi.png">
  </div>
  <div class="foo black" data-image="http://www.lilianricaud.com/travail-en-reseau/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google-chrome-300x300.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="sample">
</div>
```